# Sum on spotifre

Tags: math, sum, spotfire

I try to compare two expressions in an array on spotfire
but they do not give me the same result and I don't understand why from a mathematical point of view.

```
Sum([OUTS_P] - [OUTS_P2])
Sum([OUTS_P]) - Sum([OUTS_P2])
```

Do you have an idea in which case these two operations could be different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take this example table:

```
A    B
1    3
2    2
3    1
```

we have these two results:

```
Sum([A]) - Sum([B]) = Sum(1, 2, 3) - Sum(3, 2, 1) = 6 - 6 = 0

Sum([A] - [B]) = Sum( (1 - 3), (2 - 2), (3 - 1) ) = Sum(-2, 0, 2) = 0
```

this is what you're expecting, and this will work 100% of the time.

**unless**, of course, your table resembles this one:

```
A    B
1    3
2    
3    1
```

`B:2` is `NULL` or `(Empty)`. this table results in the expressions being evaluated as:

```
Sum([A]) - Sum([B]) = Sum(1, 2, 3) - Sum(3, 1) = 6 - 4 = 2

Sum([A] - [B]) = Sum( (1 - 3), (3 - 1) ) = Sum(-2, 2) = 0
```

the reason is because `NULL` is non-numeric; it's not possible to evaluate `2 - NULL`, and this data is ignored by `Sum()`.

---

if you want both expressions to always result in the same answer, you can create a calculated column like this for each column you'll be using in `Sum()`:

```
If([Column] is NULL, 0, [Column])
```

and then aggregate on this column instead of the original.

Comment: it still a bit strange that the sum function transform null in 0 but not the + sign...